# Date missing after knitting to PDF

Tags: r

```
total <- read.csv('spending_timeseries_total.csv')
# convert character to date
total$date_smart <- as.Date(total$date_smart, "%m/%d/%y")
# rescale the spending to million
total$spending_in_million <- total$spending/1000000
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data=total, aes(x=date_smart, y=spending_in_million, group=top_category, color=top_category))+geom_line()+xlab('Date')+ylab('Spending in million')+labs(color="Category")+ggtitle('Daily Time Series Figure of Spending by Retail Category')+theme(legend.position="bottom")+theme(plot.title=element_text(hjust=0.5))+guides(color=guide_legend(nrow=4))+theme(legend.title=element_text(size=7),legend.text=element_text(size=7))
```

Everything works fine when I plot the graph in RStudio. The x-axis has dates displayed.

The plot in RStudio:

[image: The plot in RStudio]

However, after I knitted to PDF, the date format becomes weird. I struggled for a long time but didn't figure out why.

The plot in knitted PDF:
[image: The plot in knitted PDF]

Comment: And we will also struggle to figure out went wrong with no sight of either your code or data...

Comment: Sorry for that! I've put my code for the plot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had that problem too. Have you tried first knit it as html and later save as pdf? For me  it works that way.

I was not able to use comment because I don't have enough reputation.

If that not works change the size of the plot in R.

Comment: Thanks for your response! No, I haven't solved it yet. I guess your solution is the only way.

Comment: Has it worked or not? I hope you could solve it

Comment: Yeah~ It can work. But I'm still wondering how to solve it in PDF cause I quite like the format of knitted PDF.